# How to create a 'hole' in an image in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, graphics, gdi+

I am trying to create a hole in my image using code, like this http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b595/electrogeekguy/fogofwardemo_zps6a6108c8.png

so that when i draw my image you can see what is underneath through the hole.

Below is my code that creates a gradient transparent at the middle out to solid black at the edges, but it blends my gradient with the underlying black.

vb.net or c# code to help me would be fine.

My plan is to remove a circle such as in my picture above and then apply the gradient.

```
Private Function FogOfWarUpdate() As Image
    Dim FogOfWarBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(FogOfWarOldImage)
    Dim FogOfWarGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(FogOfWarBitmap)
    Dim FogOfWarGraphicsPath As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    FogOfWarGraphicsPath.AddEllipse(2048, 1024, 500, 500)
    Dim FogOfWarPathGradientBrush As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PathGradientBrush(FogOfWarGraphicsPath)
    FogOfWarPathGradientBrush.CenterPoint = New PointF(2048 + 250, 1024 + 250)
    FogOfWarPathGradientBrush.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Black)
    FogOfWarPathGradientBrush.SurroundColors = New Color() {Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black)}
    FogOfWarGraphics.FillPath(FogOfWarPathGradientBrush, FogOfWarGraphicsPath)

    'FogOfWarGraphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.BlueViolet, 100, 100, 200, 200)
    FogOfWarPathGradientBrush.Dispose()
    FogOfWarGraphicsPath.Dispose()
    FogOfWarGraphics.Dispose()

    Return FogOfWarBitmap

End Function
```

Comment: Use the Graphics.Clip property

Comment: @HansPassant, I have looked at the clip properties, but from what I can gather it only handles rectangles.  Could you provide a link to anything that would show how to clip ellipse regions?  Thanks

Comment: you should try overlays